# Почему gem turbolinks так странно себя ведет?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems

В документации по этому gem'у сказано, что он необходим для того, чтобы получать новую страницу с сервера через ajax, парсить ее на стороне клиента и заменять только содержимое тега body и head.

Стандартное "одностраничное" приложение, получающее страницы с сервера через ajax я всегда проверял следующим, как мне кажется, надежным методом: вставлял на одну страницу тег  (в случае rails это audio_tag) и ссылку на другую страницу. Если при переходе на другую страницу по этой ссылке музыка, начавшая проигрываться на предыдущей странице, продолжила играть, значит действительно ajax работает как надо и страница не делает свой обычный цикл перезагрузки, а парсится прямо в клиенте из html, полученного с сервера.

Но в gem turbolinks, по-умолчанию установленный в rails приложение, я смотрю, все не так.

Я неправильно понимаю суть его работы? И что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Хе. Хе. Хе-хе. Хе-хе-хе-хе-хе. А `<audio>` где, в `<body>`?

Comment: @D-side Дааа, а что? Ну его как минимум нелогично было бы в head помещать.

Comment: Ну, я был под впечатлением, что заменяется весь `body` и всё, что в нём было, останавливается/умирает. Но вообще, на вид, по спеке это не так. Приложите исполняемый пример, используемый браузер и версию Turbolinks.

Comment: Так... что? Детали будут?

Comment: @D-side Да как вам сказать. В голове крутятся воспоминания того, как спокойно организовывал переход по страницам при помощи Ajax и музыка продолжала играть. Попробовал сейчас - не получается. Как я тогда это делал - не пойму. Поэтому и пример не вижу смысла выкладывать. Судя по всему такое поведение как раз обосновано, ведь, заменяя весь тег body, заменяется и тег аудио (соответственно старый тег пропадает и музыка останавливается).  
  
Конечно, в этом есть свои плюсы (скорость загрузки страницы), но, если нужно реализовать свой механизм, то весь турболинкс придется ставить на костыли.

Comment: У него есть механизм частичной замены, но он всё равно перестраивает документ и элементы при перемещении останавливаются (во вс. сл. в Хроме)... А Turbolinks 5 полностью переписан, там могут быть изменения на этот счёт.

Comment: @D-side Ладно, придется пользоваться тем, что есть. Ускоренная загрузка - это хорошо. А то, под что она не была рассчитана и для чего не разрабатывалась, видимо, придется ставить на костыли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turbolinks аяксово получает `html`-ответ от сервера и заменяет весь `body`. Информация внутри `head` не заменяется. Также есть возможность пометить какой-либо тег в `body` как перманентный, и он заменяться не будет. В пятой версии turbolinks это помечается через атрибут `data-turbolinks-permanent`.

Comment: Случайно сегодня попал на этот вопрос, сразу не заметил, что вы ответ дали. Спасибо, надеюсь, пригодится еще.